# How to input a list of attributes into a function

Tags: python, function, class, attributes

Suppose i have a class with several attributes. I want to modify a select few in the same way. However, since i can't put attributes in a list, this is rather tedious.

For example:

```
class BOB:
    def __init__(self,name,color,shape):
        self.lenname = len(name)
        self.lencolor = len(color)
        self.lenshape = len(shape)

def BOBmodify_lenname(instance):
    instance.lenname *= 2

def BOBmodify_lencolor(instance):
    instance.lencolor *= 2

def BOBmodify_lenshape(instance):
    instance.lenshape *= 2
```

My goal is to have an input of sorts in the form of a list of attribues, like [lenshape, lencolor] and then have a function that iterates over the list and multiplies them by two. Since this is not possible, i have to resort to a function for each attribute

Here, i only have three attributes, and i need three functions to modify each. For classes with more attributes, this quickly becomes impractical. It would be nice if this was possible:

```
def BOBmodify(instance,attribute_list):
    for attribute in attribute_list:
        instance.attribute *= 2
```

and then do

```
BOBmodify(bobinstance, [lenname, lenshape])
```

Aas far as i know, you can't put attributes in a list so this isn't possible. So how should i handle this situation where i want a function to do the same thing to several different attributes? Although i've searched for this on stack overflow and google, nothing relevant has come up. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a method like this, and pass attributes as strings:

```
def modify_attrs(self, attrs):
    for attr in attrs:
        val = getattr(self, attr)
        setattr(self, attr, val*2)

...

bobinstance.modify_attrs(['lenname', 'lenshape'])
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> bobinstance = BOB('spam', 'red', 'square')
>>> bobinstance.__dict__
{'lenshape': 6, 'lencolor': 3, 'lenname': 4}
>>> bobinstance.modify_attrs(['lencolor', 'lenname'])
>>> bobinstance.__dict__
{'lenshape': 6, 'lencolor': 6, 'lenname': 8}
```

Comment: The question says, you can't put attributes into lists.I think that statement is less meaningful than it sounds. An "attribute" is a part of an object, what exactly does the questioner want to put in the list? But as the answer shows, it's quite meaningful to put the *names* of attributes into a list. And, that one can write a function to do useful things based on those names.